# iPhone configuration file

Tags: c#, iphone, scripting

I try to create iPhone configuration file via c# script as proposed in "Enterprise deployment Guide" of Apple and faced the following problem :

iPCU.exe TestScript.cs 
// This command should create the profile but he not . He just run iPhone configuration //utility.  TestScrip.cs consist example from Apple's pdf.
   Maybe somebody know the way that really work ?

Comment: Sorry, am I getting this right? You are trying to program an iPhone in C#?

Comment: @RaYell: iPhone Configuration Utility is different from iPhone App programming. I think he should ask at serverfault since this seems to be an administration problem.

Comment: No. Read this document section about scripting:
http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf

Comment: @RaYell - and even if it wasn't, MonoTouch does C# on iPhone.

Comment: Maybe somebody can say something usable instead of flame ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's provided sample script fails to compile; the ipcu.log, whose location is specified in nlog.config, has:

Error: The name 'Console' does not exist in the current context

Comment out the "Console.WriteLine" or add "using System;" to your script & you will get something like:

```
[2010-02-23 15:13:32.4466 iPCU] Debug: CoreFoundation.dll - Version 8.4.441.10 
[2010-02-23 15:13:32.4466 iPCU] Debug: MobileDevice.dll - Version 8.4.238.9 
[2010-02-23 15:13:32.5946 iPCU] Debug: Saving :ee14db03-f5c0-4916-bbfa-56f9bd47775f 
[2010-02-23 15:13:32.6106 iPCU] Warn: I don't know what to do with an account of type:  
[2010-02-23 15:13:32.6106 iPCU] Warn: I don't know what to do with an account of type:  
[2010-02-23 15:13:32.8966 iPCU] Debug: SaveSettings 
[2010-02-23 15:13:32.8966 iPCU] Debug: SaveSettings 
[2010-02-23 15:13:32.8966 iPCU] Debug: SaveSettings 
[2010-02-23 15:13:32.8966 iPCU] Debug: SaveSettings 
[2010-02-23 15:13:35.9679 iPCU] Debug: Saving :UI_Identifier295f8e03-05fb-4725-a3bb-52ff20814e3f 
[2010-02-23 15:13:39.5093 iPCU] Debug: Saving :com.example.configviascript41b84468-48bd-44fd-b171-757c99ec07b8 
[2010-02-23 15:13:39.5283 iPCU] Debug: Saving :com.example.configviascript8bc2800b-e14f-4d1e-8e4e-d959d89992d0 
[2010-02-23 15:13:39.5283 iPCU] Debug: Saving :com.example.configviascriptaf655be3-8761-4d96-a582-60e26b257d75 
[2010-02-23 15:13:39.5283 iPCU] Debug: Saving :com.example.configviascriptee14db03-f5c0-4916-bbfa-56f9bd47775f
```

Despite the warnings, it will compile the script and load it into iPCU windows application.

Comment: Thank you !!!!
  To continue i have other question . If it's possible to create Configuration Script without iPCU window will be shown?

Comment: There is no documentation about this, and testing shows iPCU will always pop-up.
To avoid its visibility spawn it programmatically using the Process class, and set:
  ProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle =  ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

You then have to kill/close it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

'Configuration Profile' has an Export function which does (can be made to do) the job for plain/signed mobileconfig files.